# Expendable Listview with checkboxes in Android Child not getting values

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Hello I tried this code but parent is all set and child not taking any values and click of parent is even not working and expand the list further for display of child.

```
public class CategoryBaseAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private HashMap<Integer, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> mListDataChild;
    private ArrayList<ProfessionEntity> mListDataGroup;
    private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;
    private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
    private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
    private String groupText;
    private String childText;
    public CategoryBaseAdapter(Activity context,
            ArrayList<ProfessionEntity> listDataGroup, HashMap<Integer, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> listDataChild) {
        mContext = context;
        mListDataGroup = listDataGroup;
        mListDataChild = listDataChild;
        mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        Log.d("--grpcount--",String.valueOf(mListDataGroup.size()));
        return mListDataGroup.size();
    }
    @Override
    public ProfessionEntity getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        Log.d("---poisit",String.valueOf(groupPosition));
        return groupPosition;

    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        groupText = getGroup(groupPosition).getDecription();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
            groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
            groupViewHolder.mGroupText = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupTextView);
            convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        } else {
            groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setText(groupText);
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int i=mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition).getUsesr_type()).size();
        Log.d("--childrencount",String.valueOf(i));
        return i;
    }
    @Override
    public ProfessionChildEntity getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition).getDecription()).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
        final int mChildPosition = childPosition;
        childText = getChild(mGroupPosition, mChildPosition).getDescription();
        Log.d("---- child---",childText);
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);

            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

            childViewHolder.mChildText = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childTextView);

            childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            convertView.setTag(R.layout.child_item, null);

        } else {

            childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView
                    .getTag(R.layout.child_item);
        }

//      childViewHolder.mChildText.setText(childText);

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {
            boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);

            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);

        } else {

            boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];

            // add getChecked[] to the mChildCheckStates hashmap using mGroupPosition as the key
            mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

            // set the check state of this position's checkbox based on the 
            // boolean value of getChecked[position]
            childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {

                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                    getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                    mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

                } else {

                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                    getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                    mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                }
            }

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public final class GroupViewHolder {

        CheckBox mGroupText;
    }

    public final class ChildViewHolder {

        TextView mChildText;
        CheckBox mCheckBox;
    }
}
```